# Order of execution of Android Data Binding's Binding functions

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a requirement where the order of execution is very important , I have a TextSwitcher view where value for setFactory is set using data binding function and this view also has text attribute . Now setFactory binding method should run first then only setText have to be called because if setFactory is not called then we won't get textView to hold the text set through setText method. So How can we ensure order of execution here?
`

```
<TextSwitcher
     setFactory="@{0}"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_ins"
     android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_outs"
     android:text = "text" />
```

Comment: It appears I ran into this issue with a ProgressBar. If I set the max progress above 100 through data binding and set the progress immediately after that (through data binding or directly), the progress value is restricted to 100 because it executes before setMax. For example, with max of 200 and progress of 150, the progress bar appears to be at 1/2 instead of 3/4. My workaround at the moment is to call setMax directly, but that's not ideal since I still pass in the max value through data binding to be used by another view.